# Getting Number of weeks a month in a pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, calendar

Calculating a no of weeks in a month in pyspark.

```
date          id
01-01-2020     1
01-02-2020     2
01-03-2020     3
01-04-2020     4
```

expected dataframe

```
date          id   no of weeks
01-01-2020     1     5
01-02-2020     2     5
01-03-2020     3     6
01-04-2020     4     5
```

I used below code

```
df=df.withColumn("number_of_weeks",F.lit((calendar.monthcalendar(F.year(col('date')),F.month(col('date')))
```

I am getting

> ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a UDF for using Python modules with Spark columns. To use `F.year` and `F.month`, you also need to convert the date column to DateType first, using `to_date` and an appropriate date format string.

```
import calendar
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "number_of_weeks",
    F.udf(lambda y, m: len(calendar.monthcalendar(y, m))) 
    (
        F.year(F.to_date('date', 'dd-MM-yyyy')),
        F.month(F.to_date('date', 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
    )
)

df2.show()
+----------+---+---------------+
|      date| id|number_of_weeks|
+----------+---+---------------+
|01-01-2020|  1|              5|
|01-02-2020|  2|              5|
|01-03-2020|  3|              6|
|01-04-2020|  4|              5|
+----------+---+---------------+
```